# Leaflet: improve code for show/hide legend icon

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I'd like to know how I can improve the code below, making it better and easier to read. The idea is that when the user turns on / off the layer, their representation in the legend is also shown / hidden:

The complete example is here: https://codepen.io/marcellobenigno/pen/MZRZgg

in this part of the code is configured the functionality

```js
L.Control.Layers.include({
        getOverlays: function () {
            var control, layers;
            layers = {};
            control = this;
            control._layers.forEach(function (obj) {
                var layerName;
                if (obj.overlay) {
                    layerName = obj.name;
                    return layers[layerName] = control._map.hasLayer(obj.layer);
                }
            });
            return layers;
        }
    });

var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    var title = '<h3>LEGEND:</h3>';
    div.innerHTML = title;
    div.innerHTML += '<span id="freeBus"><i></i> Free Bus</span>';
    div.innerHTML += '<span id="campus"><i></i> Campus</span>';
    div.innerHTML += '<span id="bicycleRental"><i></i> Bicycle Rental</span>';
    return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);

function showLegend(layer) {
    var item = ".legend > span:contains(" + layer + ")";
    $(item).show();
}

function hideLegend(layer) {
    var item = ".legend > span:contains(" + layer + ")";
    $(item).hide();
}

map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
    showLegend(eventLayer.name);
});

map.on('overlayremove', function (eventLayer) {
    hideLegend(eventLayer.name);
});


$.each(control.getOverlays(), function (index, value) {
    if (!value) {
        hideLegend(index);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be using some [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) functions, jQuery magic and ES6 features ([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) to simplify your code (the latter doesn't work on IE11).

First of all, some redundant code in the `legend.onAdd` function can be removed (not necessarily making the function easier to understand):

```
legend.onAdd = map => {
  const title = '<h3>LEGEND:</h3>';
  const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend')
  div.innerHTML = title + [ //array of id/text pairs
    ['freeBus','Free Bus'],
    ['campus', 'Campus'],
    ['bicycleRental','Bicycle Rental']
  ].map(a => `<span id="${a[0]}"><i></i> ${a[1]}</span>`).join('') //mapping HTML to id/text pairs
  return div;
};
```

Secondly, we can simplify the listener functions using jQuery's [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
map.on('overlayadd', e => $(`.legend > span:contains(${e.name})`).toggle() );

map.on('overlayremove', e => $(`.legend > span:contains(${e.name})`).toggle() );
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/o8fphu6x/ To be honest, I didn't understand the `L.Control.Layers.include({...})` and the `$.each(...)` parts. Commenting them out didn't change the functionality.

PS.: This saves 13 lines of code (or up to 36 if you count the commented lines).

Comment: `L.Control.Layers.include({...})` returns the active layers, I think it's necessary if some layers are off when the application starts. And the `$.each(...)` find this layers and remove then for the legend panel. It's easier to understand if you remove one layer (or more) from the map initialization, for example: `layers: [grayscale, campus]`

Comment: improving my answer, `L.Control.Layers.include({...})` returns true if the layer is active and false, for the opposite.